# The swap widget so that the under widget has been fixed

Tags: flutter, dart, swap

I have a create so simple slidable view pager with CarouselSlider:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: CarouselSlider(
  options: CarouselOptions(
    viewportFraction: 1,
    // aspectRatio: 1,
    height: double.maxFinite,
    // enlargeCenterPage: true,
  ),
  items: List.generate(
      10,
      (i) => Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: (i % 2 == 0) ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
              Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
            ],
          )),
));
```

This is its result:

[image]

But as you can see next container connects to the first widget, I want when the first widget to be swapped to the left, the next widget appears under the first widget Not next to it. It looks like the following widget is fixed and we remove the top widget.

Comment: Please clarify the question, I can not understand the problem

Comment: Imagine you have 4 widgets on top of each other.  when you swap the first one, the second one is under the first one and does not move. Like you pick up the first widget. like.the first widget is popped from the stack  @MoazEl-sawaf

Comment: Now it's clear, check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a way to create stack page view, This is a full codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dummy_data.dart';
import 'page_view_item.dart';
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  /// The current page of the page view
   double _page = 0;

  /// The index of the leftmost element of the list to be displayed
  int get _firstItemIndex => _page.toInt();

  /// Controller to get the current position of the page view
  final _controller = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 0.5,
  );

  /// The width of a single item
  late final _itemWidth =
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * _controller.viewportFraction;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() => setState(() {
          _page = _controller.page!;
        }));
  }
   @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("LV Scroll"),
      
      ),
      body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          
          Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: _itemWidth,
                  child: FractionallySizedBox(

                    child: PageViewItem(
                      index: _firstItemIndex,
                      width: _itemWidth,
                      url: model[_firstItemIndex],

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 250,
              child: PageView.builder(
                padEnds: false,
                controller: _controller,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Opacity(
                    opacity: index <= _firstItemIndex ? 0 : 1,
                    child: PageViewItem(
                      index: index,

                      width: _itemWidth,
                      url: model[index],

                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: model.length,
              ),
            ),
          ],
    ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

}

it's result :

[image]

and its [reference](https://betterprogramming.pub/custom-horizontal-scroll-with-pageview-builder-10604dad3b30);

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package called [stacked_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked_page_view), it is very simple, lightweight, and similar to the same original `PageView` in usage.

Example Snippet:

```
PageView.builder(
  itemCount: 10,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  controller: pageController,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return StackPageView(
      controller: pageController,
      index: index,
      child: Container(
        color: (colors..shuffle()).first,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            '$index',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

[image]

**Note:** You can control the scroll axis with the property `scrollDirection` inside `PageView.builder()` with values of `Axis.vertical` or `Axis.horizontal`.

Comment: It is not the same https://gifyu.com/image/SHkaT

Comment: Check the new answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package called [expandable_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_page_view), it is a `PageView` widget adjusting its height to currently displayed page. It accepts the same parameters as classic `PageView`.

```
ExpandablePageView.builder(
  itemCount: 3,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(color: Colors.blue);
  },
),
```

[image]